# How can I specify the carryover in the first period of a two-treatment three-period crossover study (ABB/BAA)?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4

I have found a lot of information on how to analyze a 2*2 (AB/BA) crossover trial; however, there are fewer materials on how to disentangle the carryover effect when the study is designed in three periods and two sequences (ABB/BAA). It is worth mentioning that A and B are the treatments and there have been wash-out phases between the three periods.

As sample data, I would like to use the bioequivalence data from "daewr" library.

```
library("daewr")
data(bioequiv)

head(bioequiv)

  Group Subject Period Treat Carry      y
1     1       2      1     A  none 112.25
2     1       2      2     B     A 106.36
3     1       2      3     B     B  88.59
4     1       3      1     A  none 153.71
5     1       3      2     B     A 150.13
6     1       3      3     B     B 151.31
```

The variable **Carry** contains lagged information from the previous period's **Treatment**.
The model below should be able to disentangle the effects, but I don't know how to replace the *none* in the **Carry** column. I am not sure how to specify this, or how to check if the carryover effect is negligible.
If we don't replace the *none* in the **Carry** column, the undermentioned model faces a problem of multicollinearity.

```
fit <- lmer(y ~ Period+Treat+Carry+(1|Subject), bioequiv)
anova(fit)
summary(fit)
```